# How to execute command by plugging arduino to USB

Tags: arduino

The idea is:

1. Connect arduino to PC via USB port (Windows 7, administrator logged
   in)
2. System automatically execute command (for example: shutdown -s
   -t 3600)

Is it possible to make that without using proxy application on host?

Comment: I think your question is, can the Arduino issue a command to the Windows system thru the USB port? And more specifically, does a user coded program have to be running on the PC to accept those commands or can a Windows program/utility be used instead?

Comment: Exactly - that is my question.

Comment: my next question is, do you **not** want to write code or are you avoiding user written code for a reason?  Also, Windows does allow scheduling tasks in advance, so is there a specific reason for having an arduino issue commands (it is a fun question and I'm writing user code, etc., but it would be nice to understand the requirement a bit more).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two code snippets that address the fundamentals of this question.  First, is a sketch that issues a "DIR" command.  Obviously, this could be any command.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    uint8_t command[] = "dir\0";

    void setup() 
    {
     Serial.begin(9600);
     delay(10000);
     Serial.write(command, 4);
    }

    void loop() {}
```

Second, is C code that reads COM5 and after receiving a string issues a command.

```
/*
 * main.c
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 29, 2013
 *      Author: Jack Coleman
 *
 *  This software is for demonstration purposes only.
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

//
// create a console that accepts data
// from a com port and issues it as system commands.
//
void display_config(COMMCONFIG *config_comm)
{
    printf("BaudRate = ");
    switch (config_comm->dcb.BaudRate)
    {
       case CBR_9600 : printf("9600\n");
    }
    printf("Parity   = %d\n", config_comm->dcb.Parity);
    printf("StopBits = %d\n", config_comm->dcb.StopBits);
    printf("ByteSize = %d\n", config_comm->dcb.ByteSize);
    fflush(stdout);

}

main()  // Version 0
{
    HANDLE hCOM5;

    int   config_size;

    COMMCONFIG config_comm;

    int   retc;
    int   nr_read;

    char *comm_char;
    char  sysline[271];

    hCOM5 = CreateFile("COM5", GENERIC_READ, 0, 0,
                     OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hCOM5 <= 0)
    {
        printf("unable to open COM5");
        return;
    }

    GetCommConfig(hCOM5, &config_comm, &config_size);

    config_comm.dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    config_comm.dcb.Parity   = NOPARITY;
    config_comm.dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    config_comm.dcb.ByteSize = 8;

    retc = SetCommConfig(hCOM5, &config_comm, config_size);
    if (retc == 0)
    {
        printf("SetCommConfig failed.\n");
        return;
    }

    display_config(&config_comm);

    // wait here for a possible, initial
    // series of 0xFF.
    comm_char = sysline;
    do
    {
        ReadFile(hCOM5, comm_char, 1, &nr_read, NULL);

        printf("%x nr_read = %d\n", *comm_char, nr_read);
        fflush(stdout);

    } while (nr_read == 0);

    while (nr_read == 1)
    {
      if (*comm_char == 0x00)
      {
         printf("%s\n", &sysline[0]);
         fflush(stdout);

         system(&sysline[0]);
         break;

      } else {
          comm_char++;
      }

      ReadFile(hCOM5, comm_char, 1, &nr_read, NULL);

      printf("%02x\n", *comm_char);
      fflush(stdout);

    }

    return;
}
```

This was a fun little coding problem.  Several lessons were learned: 1) when communicating via a serial line, the C program will simply wait until the first byte is transmitted by the Arduino.  There are **no** syncing chars to preface the data transmission (that is, if there are any they get stripped out by the system code); 2)  It is possible to get zero (0) for the number of bytes read.

Could this be used to use an Arduino to issue a shut down command?  Yes, but the program would have to be started (i.e. scheduled) and then it would wait for the Arduino to speak.